# laravelのdd()で多次元配列でも最初から展開して表示したい

Tags: laravel

laravelのdd()でデバッグ表示しています。
便利なのですが多次元配列を表示した場合はいちいち"▶"をクリックしないと中身が全部見れません。
現在このクリック作業がかなりの手間となっています。
最初から展開されたものを見たいのですが、何か簡単な良い方法はないものでしょうか。

下記の方法だと普通の文字列はいいのですが、htmlタグ文字列が確認できません。

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($a);
echo "</pre>";
```

表示したいものは例えばこんな感じです。

```
$fruits = [
    ["apple" => 0, "price" => 100, "text" => "<div>リンゴ</div>"],
    ["orange" => 1, "price" => 200, "text" => "<div>オレンジ</div>"],
    ["banana" => 2, "price" => 300, "text" => "<div>バナナ</div>"],
];
dd($fruits);
```

Comment: ２次元配列の場合には [可変長引数リスト](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) を使って `dd(...$fruits)` とする方法が考えられます。

Comment: 目から鱗が落ちました。ありがとうございます。